# How to merge three.js renders with other HTML elements?

Tags: html, three.js, html5-canvas

I am very much new to programming, stackoverflow and everything here in general. So please bear with me.

I have made simple scenes using Three.js and some effects using HTML Canvas separately.
I'd like to know if there is anyway to combine the two, or in general, how to combine the Three.js renderer canvas with other HTML elements.

My current code includes something like :

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
renderer.domElement.id = 'WebGLCanvas';
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seamless integration of WebGL content and HTML elements is not possible. You can position HTML elements on top of the renderer's canvas element or you can do it the other way around. By setting the `alpha` flag of `THREE.WebGLRenderer` to `true`, you can place the renderer's canvas on top of other HTML content.

However, you should keep in mind that WebGL content is always rendered separately. It's not possible to merge 3D objects like meshes, lines or point clouds with HTML elements so they are sorted and rendered together.

The usage of [THREE.CSS3DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/renderers/CSS3DRenderer) in combination with `THREE.WebGLRenderer` is a good example for a proper usage. Check out the following demo that shows both renderers integrated in simple application.

https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_orthographic.html

Comment: Aaah thanks... but the THREE.CSS3DRenderer is still rendering 3d objects, yaa?
What I would like is to have a 3d model integrated on an otherwise normal webpage. 
For example, [here](https://sketchfab.com/), there is a 3d model on a blue background and some text beside it in the same space. Something as _simple_ as this should be somehow possible, no?

Comment: The term "rendering" in context of `THREE.CSS3DRenderer` is somewhat misleading since it just transform HTML elements according to the transformation of 3D objects. In any event, what sketchfab does on its start page is an integration of a canvas element in a normal website. Of course, this is nothing special and easy to do. I was referring on more advanced scenarios ;)

Comment: Aah... then can you suggest some tutorial that explains how to achieve the sketchfab result?

I stressed the _as simple as_ because I know it might be a noob question, but somehow I just can't figure it out....

Comment: Maybe like so: https://jsfiddle.net/ztjLfsm0/. As you can see, you can put a canvas element in a normal website and then use it as the drawing surface for `THREE.WebGLRenderer`.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was useful to you ;)